# Solution to fabricate data using current dataset for training: amazon machine learning

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning

I am trying to create a MODEL using Amazon machine language service, but i am facing a problem that my data set is of 20 KB and contain only 120 rows. As the data set is very small it is impossible that the learning algorithm will learn correctly the data pattern and eventually my prediction model will be incorrect.

Is there any way that amazon itself can create some data on my behalf using the data that i have provided for training ?

Comment: There's no automatic way to do this. You need a model according to which synthetic data should be generated.

Comment: can you please point me to some link/tutorial/documentation where this is mentioned. or can you please provide some example by urself @cfh

Answer (score 0):

You’re correct that 120 rows of data would not be enough to train a good model and then there is data for evaluation part too. so the data that you end up with will be 30% lesser for training.

Amazon cannot create additional data on your behalf. but if you can collect more data points but not the labels (“correct” answers that are used to train the model), you may find Amazon Mechanical Turk useful for collecting these labels.

The next question is how to use Mechanical turk , that i am unsure of and trying to learn. so can't help you on that.